# Android app chashes when I add RXAndroid an RXJava libraries to build.gradle

Tags: android, rx-android

I have this exeption when I add libraries to build.gradle.I don't know why, because when I delete libraries from buil.gradle everything works fine and I haven't got any exception.

```
07-25 15:16:44.087 5057-5057/ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng, PID: 5057
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng/ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

 Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.fragments.TestListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java) 
    at ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.fragments.TestListFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java) 
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java) 
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java) 
    at ua.provectus.mobile_project.proveng.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Fragment code:

public class TestListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;                                                                                         
private RecyclerTestAdapter recyclerTestAdapter;                                                                           
private ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();                                                                       
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;                                                                             
private LayoutManagerType currentLayoutManagerType;                                                                        
private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";                                                          
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";                                                                  
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;                                                                          

private enum LayoutManagerType {                                                                                           
    GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,                                                                                                   
    LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                          

public TestListFragment() {                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                          

@Override                                                                                                                  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                          
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                    
    events = new DataManager().getEvents();                                                                                
}                                                                                                                          

@Override                                                                                                                  
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                                                     
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                      
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_fragment, container, false);                                 
    rootView.setTag(TAG);                                                                                                  

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);                                               
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);                                                                         

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());                                                                
    currentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;                                                    
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {                                                                                      

        currentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState                                                  
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                      
    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(currentLayoutManagerType);                                                                

    recyclerTestAdapter = new RecyclerTestAdapter(events);                                                                 
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerTestAdapter);                                                                          

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh);                                         

    return rootView;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                          

public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {                                            
    int scrollPosition = 0;                                                                                                

    // If a layout manager has already been set, get current scroll position.                                              
    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {                                                                         
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager())                                           
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                      

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);                                                                          
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);                                                                         
}                                                                                                                          

@Override                                                                                                                  
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                               
    // Save currently selected layout manager.                                                                             
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, currentLayoutManagerType);                                      
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);                                                                         
}
```

}

Comment: TestListFragment make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public , add you activity fragments and layout also

Comment: When I delete this two libraries from build.gradle everything works fine

Comment: What if you remove just rxAndroid?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried but have the same error